# Are there textbooks or resources on the mathematics of networks?

Tags: reference-request, online-resources, network

I am looking for textbooks/resources that are fairly mathematically rigorous yet readable on the subject of networks.

I am looking for the mathematics of networks, its alright if it has applications or examples but it must be mathematical. I am going to begin working on a project that involves solving various problems in social networks and sensor networks and I know little to nothing about the subject, I really need to start learning about it, hence the emphasis on the math. 
Thanks in advance for all the answers.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by networks and the topics of interest? For example, do you mean : http://www.oxfordscholarship.com/view/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780199206650.001.0001/acprof-9780199206650-chapter-6 or https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/teaching/1213/PrincComm/mfcn.pdf

Comment: @Moo Well, I am looking to learn about the mathematical/theoretical formulations used to analyse networks? I am not looking at any specific topic right now, I need something that sort of gives me an idea of what kind of math is used to analyse networks, what different kinds of networks there are, that sort of thing. Does that make sense?

Comment: Oh the book by Newman looks promising, I'll see if I can get it. Do you know any more books like that?

Comment: 1. Network Routing: Algorithms, Protocols, and Architectures (The Morgan Kaufmann Series in Networking), 2. Communication Networks: An Optimization, Control, and Stochastic Networks Perspective, 3. The Art of Computer Systems Performance Analysis: Techniques for Experimental Design, Measurement, Simulation, and Modeling and many more. For Social Networks, you really want to look at Data Science, AI, Machine Learning, Deep Learning and http://www.analytictech.com/mb874/slides/foundations.pdf